# STATIC_ASSERT failure with boost::spirit::karma, but not using STATIC_ASSERT explicitly

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I am getting this STATIC_ASSERT failure just by including karma.hpp:

```
In file included from /apps/boost/include/boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp:12:0,
             from /apps/boost/include/boost/math/special_functions/math_fwd.hpp:26,
             from /apps/boost/include/boost/math/special_functions/fpclassify.hpp:19,
             from /apps/boost/include/boost/spirit/home/support/detail/sign.hpp:22,
             from /apps/boost/include/boost/spirit/home/karma/numeric/detail/numeric_utils.hpp:22,
             from /apps/boost/include/boost/spirit/home/karma/numeric/bool_policies.hpp:16,
             from /apps/boost/include/boost/spirit/home/karma/numeric/bool.hpp:29,
             from /apps/boost/include/boost/spirit/home/karma/numeric.hpp:13,
             from /apps/boost/include/boost/spirit/home/karma.hpp:15,
             from /apps/boost/include/boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp:16,
             from /home/<my header file that includes boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
             from /home/<my other header file that includes the above>
/apps/boost/include/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp: In instantiation of `struct boost::math::tools::promote_args<long double, float, float, float, float, float>':
/apps/boost/include/boost/math/special_functions/sign.hpp:114:50:   required from `int boost::math::signbit(T) [with T = long double]'
/apps/boost/include/boost/spirit/home/support/detail/sign.hpp:47:51:   required from `bool boost::spirit::detail::signbit(T) [with T = long double]'
/apps/boost/include/boost/spirit/home/karma/numeric/detail/numeric_utils.hpp:130:47:   required from here
/apps/boost/include/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:141:10: error: invalid application of `sizeof' to incomplete type `boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>'
```

What gives? The best I can figure is that the static assert guards against use of long double where it is not supported. But, I use long double elsewhere and it is fine.

**EDIT: latest development release of Boost provides a fix-ish. Grab it from SVN.

Comment: What compiler, flags, etc.? Just compiling `#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp> int main(){}` works for me on `g++ -std=c++11`.

Comment: I am not entirely sure of the flags; the Makefiles are generated with CMake and I am not asking for anything special.  I am including warning_disable.hpp, and the headers for BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT. G++ version is 4.7.3.

Comment: FYI - i just tried what GManNickG did and I get the same failure. Should I try rebuilding Boost?

Comment: Try building my snippet directly with g++ to get CMake out of the picture.

Comment: Please share how you're using Karma. It can be quite confusing to debug compile-time errors caused by Spirit. Best to treat the errors as a call stack, walk through each include file and see where it all goes wrong.

Comment: The problem seems to be the same as [this](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Spirit-Math-karma-regression-in-1-54-due-to-argument-promotion-in-math-td4650114.html). Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve it. You can try reverting the changes to `boost/math/special_functions/sign.hpp` or simply using boost 1.53.0. I've seen Igor R. respond to several boost-spirit questions so maybe you are lucky and have him tell how he approached this problem.

Comment: Update: it seems the issue is specific to 1.54.0, based on the thread that cv_and_he pointed to. I am loath to revert to 1.53.0, but I am not sure what else to do. The problem appears to be simply including the karma.hpp header.